# Burninate [draconic-bloodline]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

What the [draconic-bloodline](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/draconic-bloodline) is about? Is it relevant? Should we burninate it?

If not, can we do a tag wiki on it?

Comment: I assume you're just trying to drive more traffic to [the best-titled question around here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67530/23970), and I approve =D

Answer (score 20):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): the [draconic-bloodline](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/draconic-bloodline) tag has been merged (but not synonymed) with [sorcerer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorcerer).

---

Draconic Bloodline is like a subclass of sorcerer in Pathfinder and D&D 5e. Having a tag for this is kind of like having the tags [archfey-pact], [the-fiend-pact], and [the-great-old-one-pact] for the different kinds of core D&D 5e warlock subclasses — which is to say, it's a little bit odd for this tag to exist.

I don't think it's a good or useful tag; of the questions currently bearing it…

- [one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60203/does-draconic-breath-qualify-for-metabreath-feats) is (mis)using the tag for an unrelated concept.
- [two](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/74589/why-are-there-damage-differences-with-these-breath-weapons) are [using](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111010/will-these-low-level-sorcerer-spells-and-abilities-stay-useful-for-a-high-level) this tag *instead* of the [sorcerer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorcerer) tag they should be using as well as (or instead of) [draconic-bloodline](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/draconic-bloodline).
- [one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67530/i-roll-to-seduce-the-dragon-or-do-doublings-of-proficiency-bonus-stack) is using it to label a part of the question that is merely background* for the actual problem about bonus stacking.
- **only [one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59168/does-the-natural-armor-bonus-from-the-draconic-bloodline-stack-with-racial-bonus)** is even actually worthy of the tag (assuming the tag merits existence), since that question is actually directly about a draconic bloodline's mechanics.

I don't think past usage demonstrates any value to the tag, and looking at analogies to parallel D&D/PF concepts shows that we simply don't have tags for that sort of thing — such as the various D&D 5e Warlock Pacts, or the Eldritch Knight subclass, or whatever.

All these questions could be tagged [sorcerer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorcerer) just fine.

**I think [draconic-bloodline](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/draconic-bloodline) should just be merged with [sorcerer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorcerer).** That would make all questions currently using the tag get a sorcerer-related tag relevant to all five questions, and eliminate a tag that's pretty useless. (And by merging with mod tools, we'd avoid question-bumping edits.) And by merging them without also synonymising them, the [draconic-bloodline](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/draconic-bloodline) tag stays possible to re-create if it should ever actually be useful. As doppelgreener pointed out, the current minimal usage suggest a redirection isn't needed to help people find the [sorcerer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorcerer) tag.

---

* <sub>Labelling background info is nearly always a harmful use for a tag, since it pollutes the search results with irrelevant questions.</sub>

Comment: I don’t really like synonym in this case. Maybe if re-creation keeps being a problem, but it’s just so easy to imagine game systems having something called “draconic bloodline” having nothing to do with anything called “sorcerer,” which could make this synonym awkward.

Comment: @KRyan That could happen, but in current practice it's = “sorcerer” and would be useful now. We don't usually worry about hypotheticals until they're non-hypothetical or there are extenuating circumstances; in this case the fix would be trivial if it that ever happens.

Comment: +1 to merge, but no to synonym. I agree with KRyan, and since it's minimal effort difference to choose not to create a synonym in the first place, we don't need to close that door nor create that meta work, nor does the current minimal usage suggest a redirection is needed. But I agree we don't need it right now as its own tag.

Comment: @doppel Ah! "…nor does the current minimal usage suggest a redirection is needed." That is an excellent point about needs-based action. Enough that I'll revise the answer.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie This move has sat in high support for about a week now -- want to do the honours?

Comment: @doppelgreener With pleasure!

Answer (score -6):

5 questions about a class feature that is endemic to D&D is not much, but it is a rather complicated and wide spectum one. while it is not necessary much, we do have [wild-shape](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wild-shape) (166 questions) - thus I vote to stay for the time...